# Is there any way to avoid including branch history when resolving merge conflicts when cherry picking a commit

Tags: git

I have a branch structure like follows. 3 branches.

```
a - b - c - d  *main*
     \
      e - f    *feature1*
           \
            h  *feature2*
```

Feature1 and Feature2 are actually completely independent technically. I just wanted to test feature2 with feature1 code in there. But a change in plans mean I need to put feature2 into main before I put feature1 in.

So the goal is to cherry pick `h` into `d` on `main`.

Here is my sort of confusion. When I look at the diff in a viewer like Fork the diff is incredibly clean. In fact it is exactly what I would like to cherry pick. Just the line changes shown when I look at the changes in commit `h`.

The problem is that when I go to main and try to cherry pick in `h` it merge conflicts. And in that merge conflict is code from commits `e` and `f` which I guess technically makes sense as it is cherry picking the entire file state but makes cherry picking the commit much more difficult.

I tried saving commit `h` as a patch but it won't apply on `d` because of conflicts. I tried rebasing `feature2` on `main` first but that has the same problem. Bottom line: the diff I see when I look at the diff for `h` is the exact diff I want to apply to `d`. Because there is a merge conflict it feels like the history of `e` and `f` are brought into the cherry picking of `h`. If I could somehow extract the diff of `h` on `f` and apply it to `d` that would be more what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict means that the changes in `h` build on changes in `e` and `f`. Since `e` and `f` are not in main, `h` cannot apply cleanly.

There is a clear dependency between `h` and `e`+`f`, and that's what the conflict tells you.

If the two features, Feature1 and Feature2 are conceptually/semantically independent, such that either can exist without the other, the conflict means that the implementations are textually interleaved or coupled and cannot be separated automatically (eg, one subroutine implements two distinct features). You'll need to resolve the conflict. When you eventually merge Feature1 into main, you'll have another conflict.

The conflict seems like a pain, but it tells something about the quality of the code, ie, that distinct features are not well separated. Rewrite it.